# How do i filter request from a json using curl?

Tags: grep, curl, awk

so I recently deployed this Go app on the web `https://20200329t202730-dot-ipengine-dev.appspot.com/` and the format that it shows the IP currently is

```
{
    "ip": "169.254.1.1"
}
```

How do I only get the `169.254.1.1` if I am using curl?

Keep in mind this is an example every single user will have a different IP.

THE ANSWER IS

```
curl -s 'https://20200329t202730-dot-ipengine-dev.appspot.com' | jq -r '.ip'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -s 'https://20200329t202730-dot-ipengine-dev.appspot.com' | jq -r '.ip'
```

This is the answer to grep something using curl.